# Securely reading password and passing it to multiple scripts - pass string to processes expecting input

Tags: bash, unix

I have a set of scripts that require a password to work, I coded them so that they read the password from user input instead of e.g. reading an argument or from a file so that the password is not persisted to the disk or shows on `top`.

I want to start all of them and avoid having to enter the same password multiple times.

The idea is to have a parent script that reads the password once then passes it somehow to all these scripts.

So first, in parent `start_all.sh` script:

`read -p "pass > " pass`

Now, I can't figure out how to use the value of `$pass` to start up all the child scripts that need that same password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to pass the actual password on the command line to the subordinate scripts ...

One idea using a nameref:

```
$ head parent child
==> parent <==
#!/usr/bin/bash

stty -echo                        # disable echo of password value on command line
read -p "pass > " pass
stty echo                         # re-enable echo of command line typing

export pass                       # make available to subordinate scripts
child pass                        # pass *name* of variable containing password

==> child <==
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -n newpass="$1"           # define nameref
echo "child/pwd: ${newpass}"
```

Comment: oh, using an env var is a good idea! let me test. The child script is actually just running a NodeJs interpreter btw, which needs to read the password

Comment: based on your question/description I assume this would be sufficient 'security' for your env otherwise this won't get you past other monitoring issues (eg, key logger, process (memory) snooping, etc)

Comment: I understand this is not 100% secure, but this is what I needed yes.